# How to get predicted values in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

In Keras test sample evaluation is done like this

```
score = model.evaluate(testx, testy, verbose=1)
```

This does not return predicted values. There is a method `predict` which return predicted values

```
model.predict(testx, verbose=1)
```

returns

```
[ 
[.57 .21 .21]
[.19 .15 .64]
[.23 .16 .60] 
.....
]
```

`testy` is one hot encode and its values are like this

```
[
[1 0 0]
[0 0 1]
[0 0 1]
]
```

How can the predicted values like `testy` or how to convert the predicted values to one hot encoded?

**note**: my model looks like this

```
# setup the model, add layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the model
model.fit(trainx, trainy, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=iterations, verbose=1, validation_data=(testx, testy))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The values being returned are probabilities of each class. Those values can be useful because they indicates the model's level of confidence.

If you are only interested in the class with the highest probability:

For example`[.19 .15 .64]` = `2` (because index 2 in the list is largest)

**Let the model to it**

Tensorflow models have a built in method that returns the index of the highest class probability.

```
model.predict_classes(testx, verbose=1)
```

**Do it manually**

[argmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax) is a generic function to return the index of the highest value in a sequence.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a session
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Output Values
output = [[.57, .21, .21], [.19, .15, .64], [.23, .16, .60]]

# Index of top values
indexes = tf.argmax(output, axis=1)
print(indexes.eval()) # prints [0 2 2]
```

Comment: The values being returned are probabilities, not log likelihoods.

Comment: what does verbose=1 do?

Comment: Question: How can I then get the label name based on the index? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Keras returns a np.ndarray with the normalized likelihood of class labels.
So, if you want to transform this into a onehotencoding, you will need to find the indices of the maximum likelihood per row, this can be done by using `np.argmax` along axis=1. Then, to transform this into a onehotencoding, the `np.eye` functionality can be used. This will place a 1 at the indices specified. The only care to be taken, is to dimensionalize to appropriate row length.

```
a #taken from your snippet
Out[327]: 
array([[ 0.57,  0.21,  0.21],
       [ 0.19,  0.15,  0.64],
       [ 0.23,  0.16,  0.6 ]])

b #onehotencoding for this array
Out[330]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])

n_values = 3; c = np.eye(n_values, dtype=int)[np.argmax(a, axis=1)]
c #Generated onehotencoding from the array of floats. Also works on non-square matrices
Out[332]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

The function `predict_classes()` will be deprecated. Now in order to obtain the one hot encoding you will have only to do on **softmax** `(model.predict(q) > 0.5).astype("int32")`.